# List Divider for Collapsible Content? Possible?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to have a content divider for Collapsible Content, not a list, in jQuery Mobile?

Comment: If "Collpasible Content" a product name, or just bad capitalization?

Comment: Is "If" "Is", or just a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can put anything inside a collapsible block, so it can be a grid with any proportions or a listview.

If you want a divider on the clickable part of the collapsible, then you'll have to hack it yourself with some CSS

Comment: I see, figured it would have to be some custom CSS. I notice that my custom CSS is not reading. Looks like it's being dominated by the jQuery CSS. How can I trump these styles? The !important mark isn't working. Things only work if I have inline styles, but I want to use external CSS. Any thoughts?

Comment: Looks like my CSS was reading externally to the linked CSS of the jQuery site. I missed this observation and had to simply change my links to read the downloaded files within my site. This problem is all set.